# Programatically insert line of code before end of method body

Tags: c#, file-io, unity-game-engine, post-processing

What I wanna do is to programatically insert a line of code (**C#**, meaning open an existing file and write to it) (see below):

I have **MyClass.cs**:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public void HelloWorld()
  {
    //hello world
    switch(somevalue)
    {
      case derp:
      //do something here
      break;
    }
    <--------INSERT CODE HERE -------->
  }
}
```

What is the best approach to doing this? How can I find the method "HelloWorld" and then find the "matching" closing bracket (**}**)?

Many will probably wonder why I want this (since it seems kinda stupid). I want this because I'm writing a PostProcess-script for Unity when building for Windows Store Apps. And some things are required to be added manually after each new build (and I wanna make this automatically to minimize the amount of stuff that can go wrong/forgotten).

**EDIT**

Apparently I wasn't clear enough. 
The above code is just an ***example*** meaning, it won't look exactly like the code example above. There may or may not be a switch case. There may be additional `{` and `}` characters (although there will always be a matching start and end bracket). There is no "placeholder", meaning there is no "*<--------INSERT CODE HERE -------->*" that I can just find and replace. If things were that easy I wouldn't be asking for help! Sorry if I was unclear, but I honestly thought I gave enough information.

Comment: Easiest way would be to include a comment line with a predefined placeholder. Search for that placeholder and do your replace string.

Comment: Could you get the effect you wanted using Preprocessor Directives?

Comment: I don't have that "placeholder", thought it was kinda obvious I didn't. :/ Also, I can't simply "include" that comment line, since the file itself i generated by Unity.

Comment: Do you have access to Visual Studio 2015? They added utilities that can parse code and find this kind of information out (I don't know how it works with Unity though).

Comment: Will "HelloWorld()" always just have that switch statement inside?

Answer (score 2):

Given some constraints:

1. The class doesn't contain string literals with open/close braces.
2. The methods to which you need to insert the line are always at the 2nd level of nesting of braces.
3. You need to insert the line to all such methods.
4. Maybe some other constraints?

you can write a simple program like I just wrote in JavaScript:

```
var str = '{test{test2{test3}{test4}}{test5}}';

var stack = [];

var result = '';
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    var chr = str[i];
    var resChr = chr;
    if(chr == '{') {
        stack.push(chr);
    }
    if (chr == '}') {
        stack.pop();

        if (stack.length == 1) {
            resChr = 'your line;' + chr;
        }
    }

    result += resChr;
}

console.log(result);
```

JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dus2jj63/

The result will be

```
{test{test2{test3}{test4}your line;}{test5your line;}}
```

The code may look ugly and you can make a lot of optimizations here. You can also add simple tweaks if you need to find a method with specific name.

P.S. first tried to solve it with regex but turned out not to be so easy.

P.S.S. Another JsFiddle with the example that you provided https://jsfiddle.net/xhezcg7a/

Comment: Thank you for coming up with a solution! I just recently managed to write a working piece myself (which I will post here soon). As yours, mine also has some flaws (for example string literals with '{', '}'). Mine however should work on any level of nesting.

Comment: Regex is the way to go, IMO (as long as the pattern of the code inside MyClass is predictable). MUCH less code/simpler to understand. I tweaked my answer with an expression that works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//this should return what you want
Regex.Replace(
       fileContents, 
       //after the first closing brace found in HelloWorld(). Tweak to taste.
       @"(?<=          (?# text is preceded by...)
        HelloWorld()   (?# the HelloWorld function)
        [^}]*})        (?# code up to the first closing brace)
        \s*?           (?# the first whitespace after the first closing brace)"
       Environment.Newline + newCode, 
       RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Note, it's basically one line of code. My motto is "simple is better" and "less code means less to maintain".

Comment: you're not using any Regex...what's the benefit of that over `string.Replace` here?

Comment: I don't have that "placeholder", thought it was kinda obvious I didn't. :/

Comment: The advantage of Regex.Replace() is that it didn't assume a simple placeholder. I suspected the placeholder might not exist, and ended up being right. The OP simply needs to plop a different argument in (and I can help him with that).

Comment: I tweaked the answer to use an expression I think will work. It assumes that you want the code inside the second to last closing curly brace.

Comment: Thanks for this elegant solution! I haven't had the time to try it out yet. I can agree on your motto, only, regex is hieroglyphs to me! ;)

Comment: Some problems with this solution is:
1. This matches as you said "second-to-last" closing brace. Meaning it will always insert it in the last method in the class, which is not always the case.
2. How would one insert "tabs" or "whitespace" as to match the row above/before?
Using regex is really awesome, but limits (atleast for me) the possibilities to modify even further!

Comment: Where do you want the code inserted, then? Before the closing brace of a method named "HelloWorld()"? It wouldn't be hard to tweak the expression, but the requirements will need to be clarified. The whitespace thing can be determined, but do you really care for generated code? Even if you do it's probably easiest just to add tabs to the code you insert, as long as you can assume the level of indentation.

Comment: I tweaked the expression. It now inserts code right after the first closing brace found in the HelloWorld() function (basically after the switch statement). The regex assumes that HelloWorld()'s guts follow a consistent pattern with the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

You really haven't provided enough information here for a solid answer.

The easiest way is to use `string.Replace` to replace your *"<--------INSERT CODE HERE -------->"* text with whatever you want to insert.

But it isn't entirely clear if that text actually appears in the file you are modifying.

In the end, if you really need to find the end of the method without any known marker, then you'll need a much more complex parser to identify the method and where it ends. That is doable but a major task, and well beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: I don't have that "placeholder", thought it was kinda obvious I didn't. :/ Thanks for going a step beyond and saying it will be much more complex.

Comment: All the other replies assumed you did have a placeholder, so I guess I wasn't the only one who at least questioned that. I've written a lot of parsers in C#, including a [JavaScript formatter](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-javascript-formatter) that is used in Fiddler. Yes it can be done, but it's a major effort. Basically, you need to identify all the elements of the language to determine context.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to piece together a "working" solution. It has some of the flaws that medvedev1088 mentions. It can probably be optimized and whatnot. I use the code below to find the `lineNumber`. When the amount of `{` found matches the amount of `}` found the end of the method should have been found, assuming the use of '}' didn't occur in some text-context.

Then I use `StreamWriter` to write all the same lines. When it comes to `lineNumber`, it writes `the-code-i-wanna-insert` and the closing bracket (`}`).

```
private static int FindEndOfMethod(string filename, string methodToFind)
{
    int countStartBracket = 0;
    int countEndBracket = 0;

    string line = "";
    int lineNumber = -1;

    bool foundEnd = false;
    bool foundMethod = false;

    System.Action countBrackets = () =>
    {
        if (line.Contains("{"))
            countStartBracket++;
        if (line.Contains("}"))
            countEndBracket++;

        //If we found the method and the start and end bracke- count is the same we found the end (and they are not zero)
        if (foundMethod && countStartBracket == countEndBracket && countStartBracket != 0 && countEndBracket != 0)
            foundEnd = true;
    };


    //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        //Continue to read until you reach end of file
        while (line != null)
        {
            lineNumber++;

            //Read next line, if it's null, we reached end of file and didn't find the place
            if ((line = sr.ReadLine()) == null)
                return -1;

            //If we haven't found the method yet, we check each line to see if it's on this line
            if (!foundMethod)
                if (line.Contains(methodToFind))
                    foundMethod = true;

            //If it was or has been found we count brackets to determine the closing one
            if (foundMethod)
                countBrackets();

            if (foundEnd)
            {
                Debug.Log(lineNumber);
                return lineNumber;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```